# custom CSS - stuck, i've tried all sorts of combinations

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I know this must be simple, but I am just absolutely stuck! I want to change the below to www.readyprint.biz:

1. When you hover a button (e.g. products) it’s purple/lavender – i want to change it to blue
2. I want to change the social icon colours – at moment it’s purple/lavender, i want to change it to white

I've tried:

```
.color-linen #menu-primary li.current-menu-item>a:hover{
background: #42b1fe;
}
```

But that doesnt work.... same logic I applied to the social icons. I right click the icons in browser, click inspect, and try and figure it out on the CSS section.

please help!

This is a wordpress site by the way, and I'm using a CSS plugin to handle the CSS.

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you create a snippet (or a jsfiddle) that demonstrates the issue? Because I made [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/p9o5564t/) based on your source, and it works. So the problem must be with those parts of the source you're not showing.

Comment: When I hover the products link i'm seeing it change to blue, not lavender.    The second issue can be resolved with this -> #footer #menu-social-menu a:before {
    color: #fff;
}

Comment: perfect joplo - thank you. Works.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have already fixed the issue didn't u?
When I visit readyprint.biz the menu item is blue when I hover the mouse.

Maybe u should refresh your webpage.

Edit:
To change the icon to white.
Go to the code:

```
color-linen #footer a:focus {
color: #565656;
 }
```

Change the #565656 to #000000

Comment: yes dennis - i fixed that already - it just came to me like a bolt of lightning :)